# Anamorphism in Banana, Lenses and Barbed wires

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Shouldn't

`g a = (a,a)` 
in the definition of anamorphism for `iterate` in here? I find that, `f` is not applied for the `zip` case. Or am I reading it wrong?

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.41.125&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `g a = (a, f a)` is the correct definition. I'm not sure I understand your objection about `zip`; the two functions `iterate` and `zip` are not really related. They are both implemented as anamorphisms in this paper, but the similarities basically end there -- and they don't share any code other than the definition of an anamorphism.

You can verify that these definitions are correct yourself by transcribing his math to Haskell:

```
import Prelude hiding (iterate)

anamorphism g p b | p b = []
                  | otherwise = a : anamorphism g p b'
    where (a, b') = g b

iterate f = anamorphism g (const False)
    where g a = (a, f a)
```

Then, in ghci:

```
> take 10 (iterate succ 0)
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

This jives with the built-in:

```
> take 10 (Prelude.iterate succ 0)
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```